# jquery DataTable data format and Warning - added data does not match known number of columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-plugins, datatables

I have a function that loads json data into a jquery dataTable

```
(...)
success: function (response) { LoadData(response.d); }
(...)

function LoadData(data)
        {
            $('#tableAnalysis').dataTable({
            "aaData" : data
            });
        }
```

My "data" looks like this:

```
{"d":[{"Key":"sometext","Value":891},{"Key":"someothertext","Value":287},{"Key":"moretext..","Value":233}]}
```

my html table looks like this:

```
<table id="tableAnalysis">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Label</th>
      <th>Frequency</th>
    </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
    <tr>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I keep receiving "Warning - added data does not match known number of columns".

How should I handle my "data" in order to be in the proper format for dataTables? What is the proper format?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Although you can pass an array to aaData, I don't think you can pass it a JSON "object" the way you are doing. You can pass a straight array or an array of objects only. But you shouldn't need to do an Ajax call followed by populating aaData, because  DataTables itself already has built-in Ajax functionality. To perform an Ajax data retrieval and then display it, you can do it all within the dataTable() function itself:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#tableAnalysis').dataTable( {
    "sAjaxSource": "http://someurl.com/someresource.jsp" // obviously, a fake URL
  });
})
```

The expected format is JSON. However, it is expecting the JSON to be formatted a certain way, including the use of the aaData parameter, which would include the data (just more JSON) in the expected way.

Once that is sorted out, you may need to review whether the data set matches the number of available columns (2), but there's no point worrying too much about it until you're passing the expected data into the dataTable() function.

So, about the data. You can see an example here: http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/ajax.html

If you go the `sAjaxSource` route, your data also needs to be formatted differently than you are doing:

```
{
    "aaData": [
        [
            "sometext",
            891
        ],
        [
            "someothertext",
            287
        ],
        [
            "moretext",
            233
        ]
    ]
}
```

If your resource returns data formatted this way, I can't see why it wouldn't work. Part of me is worried about the `<tr>` elements that contain no `<td>` but I haven't double-checked the requirements in that regard.

---

As an aside: with your original JSON, you're showing a bit of a misunderstanding about how JavaScript key-value pairs are created. You have a key called "Key" with a value of "sometext" and then another key called "Value" with a value of "891" for example. There are ways you COULD use this schema I suppose, but the semantics of it start to get confusing. ;-) Most of the time you don't call your key "Key", it just *IS* the key:

```
{
  "name" : "Greg",
  "species" : "monkey",
  "level" : 9000
}
```

In this associative array, everything on the left of the colons is a key, and everything on the right is a value.